# Display images from server in listview

Tags: image, listview, directory

My images are stored in a folder "Albums" and address for those images are "/Albums/..". i want to concatenate two strings in imageurl but its not working and listview is not displaying images:here is my code:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="listView" 
                            OnItemDataBound="ContactsListView_ItemDataBound">
                            <ItemTemplate>

                           <asp:Image ID="img"  ImageUrl= '<%# String.Concat("/", Eval("PictureLink")) %>' runat="server" />

                            </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:ListView>
```

any help?